# Qt how use OCI driver without installing Oracle client

Tags: qt, oracle11g, qt4, oracle-call-interface

Is there a way to use the Qt OCI driver without installing Oracle client ? Maybe using static libs from Oracle while we build the driver? Or using some Oracle client dlls and with some env variable setup?

The thing is I can't ask my clients to install oracle client before using my application. They expect my application to up and running without any hassle.

If this cannot be achieved then what do we have as alternatives?

- OS=Windows 7
- Qt=4.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested this is how I have done it.

1. Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci01int.htm#423364 Forget about patching part.
2. Download oracle instant client http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html. This is a zip file, no installation required, just extract it application contains. (alternatively we can extract somewhere else and include the location into Path env variable)
3. As now we don't have client installed, we don't have a tnsnames.ora file also. So set the ip, port and service name directly. (Alternatively we can use TNS_ADMIN env variable if we want tnsnames.ora file badly) Ex:

```
   o_Database.setHostName("10.10.10.225");
   o_Database.setPort(1521);
   o_Database.setDatabaseName("ora11g");
```

4. That is it. It should work perfectly.

Meantime, it is legal to distribute the Oracle instant client DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? Are your intentions purely technical or do you have problems with licensing? (Oracle does not allow redistribution of OCI libs). What OS are you using?

On Linux/AIX you can theoretically create you own "static" version of OCI lib. The dynamic one is called libclntsh (sh - stands for shared). The static one libclntst can be at least build manually by using Oracle's makefiles.
Then you can technically embed this static library in your application. You might have some missing symbols (for example __fast_memcpy_A). It's because Oracle was compiled using Intel's ICC compiler and you have also add static version of some ICC's runtime libs.

You can also look at project [Tora](https://sourceforge.net/p/tora/code/HEAD/tree/). There users have to download OCI libs manually and have all ale Oracle specific code is put into separate plugin.

Update: AFAIK Oracle does not allow re-distribution of OCI.DLL unless you are Oracle Business Partner (or however is it called these days).

In case of Windows platform you can use:

- Microsoft's ODBC driver for Oracle. It should be present in every Windows installation. But this one is very old and does not support newer data-types (like LOBs) and maybe it does not also support some charsets.
- Some 3rd party oci-like driver. But AFAIK it is available only for C#.
- Use some application server and not use direct DB connection from client apps
- Write your own driver. See [Pythian](http://www.pythian.com/blog/repost-oracle-protocol/).

Comment: My intentions are either link oracle statically or distribute dlls. But not sure about the licensing as I haven't go through those.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll check those.